# iOS Core Data Performance with large datasets

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I maintain and develop an existing native Objective-C iOS app that holds contact information for around 100k people.  We would now like to introduce a segmentation strategy that will restrict the visibility of these 100k records.  The segmentation strategy needs to be flexible, and will be driven by things such as the currently logged-on user level (& company division), and some 'tagging' filters (show anyone with a tag of 'Hot Prospect' or 'Big Spender' or 'Likes Boats').

So, I am contemplating tagging all the 100k contacts with several tags each.  This would allow me to run compound searches where I want anyone called 'John' with a tag of 'Hot Prospect' who 'Likes Boats'.  Etc, etc.  Users will be able to define and add tags themselves.

My question is this: with 100k contacts, and, say, 10 tags per contact, I will have 1M tag records in my core data object graph.  The tags will be indexed.  Am I going to hit performance problems?  Is core data on an iPad mini running iOS8 going to struggle with this, or can I start designing/building the segmentation strategy without worrying about performance (assuming I code it right)?  Does my tagging strategy sound solid, with each contact having a 1-many relationship to several tags?

Comment: Sorry if this is pedantic, but the contact-tag relationship should be many-many, not 1-many.  Not only can each contact have many tags, but each tag will apply to many contacts.  The number of tags will be far lower than 1M (I assume!), but the number of rows in the join table might be up in the 1M.  Though none of that fundamentally affects your question.

Comment: You're not being pedantic, you're just being right!  It is a valid point :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that it is hard to estimate the runtime behavior at the very beginning. It is more an experienced guessing instead of engineering. And Donald Knuth was right.

However, the runtime behavior for searching on such a data set will depend heavily on the fact, whether CD can map your predicates to SQL directly. In such a case the real work is done inside SQLite and less data by far is loaded. Likely that will work fine. If CD cannot map the predicate to SQL, data has to be loaded and this will make your app slow.

So what I would do: Built a minimal test schema for your use case and try to execute the predicates you want to execute.

- Will this work or does CD reject that predicates?
- If it accepts the predicates, turn verbose mode of CD on and have a look on the SQL commands (in verbose mode, CD prints out that commands) and check, whether they are reasonable.